# Ember js store and pass clicked {{#link-to}} property to Route model

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to Ember.js, and I am trying to learn it by rewriting an old app of mine. Unfortunately I got stuck fairly early and need some help, as couldn't find the answer on the Web.

I have the following code:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
 LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function () {
 this.resource("users", function () {
  this.resource("score", {path: "/:nickname"});
 });
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function () {
  var url = "server url";
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   resolve($.getJSON(url));
  });
 }
});

App.ScoreRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function () {
  var url = "server url" + "?nickname=";
  url += passedNicknameFromclickedLink;
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   resolve($.getJSON(url));
  });
 }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
 <nav>
  {{#link-to "users"}}Users{{/link-to}}
 </nav>
 <main class="main-wrapper">{{outlet}}</main>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
 <div class="user-score">{{outlet}}</div>
 <h2>Users</h2>
 {{#each}}
  <div>{{#link-to "score" nickname}}{{nickname}}{{/link-to}}</div>
  <div>{{games}}</div>
  <div>{{score}}</div>
 {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="score">
 <h2>Score for {{nickname}}</h2>
 {{#each categoryScores}}
  <div class="scores">
   <div>{{category}}</div>
   <div>{{gamesPlayed}}</div>
   <div>{{score}}</div>
  </div>
 {{/each}}
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is to take the {{nickname}} property clicked by the user in the {{#link-to}} in "users" template and pass it as "passedNicknameFromclickedLink" variable to App.ScoreRoute in order to make a server request. I was wondering what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've almost everything right, you just need 2 things. First, you can access the `nickname` dynamic segment in the `model` hook with the [params](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) parameter.

```
model: function(params) {
    var passedNicknameFromclickedLink = params.nickname;
}
```

Secondly, because Ember assumes quite a few conventions with your route and models, you'll have to override the [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) method in the route as well. With the `serialize` method, what you want to do is start with your model (the JSON from the server) and give back the nickname that was used to find that model. I don't know exactly what your JSON looks like, but it might look something like this:

```
serialize: function(model) {
    return encodeURI(model.nickname);
}
```

Comment: Hi GJK and thank you for your answer. It is exactly what I needed. I did not even need to override the serialize method.